# File Not Found Exception, Identical Directory Exists

Tags: java, file

However the file appears to be there. Under FileOne.txt's properties the directory is listed as; 
C:\Users\Rig\Desktop\Java

The code is as follows,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Parse{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hey gurl hey World!");
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Rig\\Desktop\\Java\\FileOne.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String nextToken = input.next();
            System.out.println("Hey gurl hey World!");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Edit: This issue has been resolved, consult Masud's answer.

Comment: `Txt` vs `txt` or is that just a typo in the post?

Comment: Good eye, and thanks! Alas, I have changed it and still tried to run it with no luck; I'll be modifying the post momentarily to reflect that.-

Comment: @user3117081 can you replace \\ by /

Comment: Amir, unfortunately "\" is the Java escape character, it's impossible to have just the one in this context unless you preface the string with an "@"(I believe).

Comment: File not found can mean "Access is denied"

Comment: @user3117081 usually it works if you just replace it with / that what I do all the time. But it seams that this does not solve you question

Comment: @user3117081 As user x2 mentioned in his comment, you may not have permissions to access the file. Please post the entire stack trace that you obtain after executing the program.

Comment: Are you logged in as Rig? If not, you either need to log in as Rig, or log in as Administrator.

Comment: `Scanner(File)` throws `FileNotFoundException`. Does this code even compile?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: This has been resolved, see Masud's answer below.

Comment: @user3117081 Then you should accept Masud's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If your path is correct than you should read your file. But, you need to catch or throw `FileNotFoundException` to compile or run.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

  .....
 }
```

Comment: I tried making this change, and it threw all sorts of errors.

Comment: @user3117081 what kind of errors? Post the traceback.

Comment: This should work. With this modification it works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you Masud you were absolute right, I forgot to import the .io for FileNotFoundException! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3117081 aren't you using an IDE with auto-import?

Comment: Eclipse, because I need a quick and simple parsing program for big data; and I'm much more used to web development. Happy to hear any recommendations however :P

Comment: Yes, but I thought that Eclipse had the auto-import feature. So, how did you forget to import `.io`?

Comment: A symbol appears on the left hand side of the code, I believe if you right click it it will offer solutions; I clicked the solution that looked the most intuitive. To be honest. Then it added, "import java.io.FileNotFoundException;"

Answer (score 0):

you wrongly typed the file type txt instead you give Txt.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Rig\\Desktop\\Java\\FileOne.txt");
```

Comment: @user3117081 so what?there is any restriction.

Comment: Well, that may have been an issue; but it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be your FileName is FileOne.Txt and the whole file name is FileOne.Txt.txt including textpad extension.
So the whole path will be 
C:\Users\Rig\Desktop\Java\FileOne.Txt.txt

Comment: There is no redundant .txt at the end of the file's name; the file's name is "FileOne.txt" not "FileOne.Txt.txt"